# I'm trying to apply this effect (like pushing a window from down to top) for my other code but it's not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJOpXr) effect (just like pushing a window from down to top) for my other [code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMVOLK) but it's not working. I don't know what's wrong with the code.

CSS:

```
  label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50;
  width: 16%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
}


label::after {
  z-index: 1;
  background: green;  /* ::after background */
  transform: scale3d(1, 0.1, 1);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}


input:focus + label::after {
  transform: scale3d(1, -1, 1);
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so `+` operator works on `label` after the `input` element

kindly check that your `input` is before than `label` in your code

and where it is working `label` is after `input` tag in html

read more about it 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="text" name="name" class="input-field" id="user"/> <!--input filed-->
  <label for="user">Username: </label>
```

try reverting the input and label position

You are applying css like **input+label** as per your current code its **label+input** which is wrong